# condition using char in java

Tags: java

Just wondering how do I print this. If the user input condition is correct? Trying to make it print out later to display results

```
if(SkillLevel > 1) {
        System.out.println("Would you like to sign up for medical y/n?");
        Medical = sc.next().charAt(0);
        if (Medical == 'y') {
            TotalPay = TotalPay -  23.50;
        }

       if(Medical == "y") {
           System.out.println("\nMedical Insurance cost : -$23.50");    
       }

}
```

Comment: Why are u using the same if conditions twice in one u are matching with string and in another you are using character.Remember for string comparisions u have to use equals() mehod not ==

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both the display and the calculation happen if the first `char` is `'y'`, then you only need the first if-statement.

Not only that, but your second if statement can never be true, because the types are incompatible (`String` and `char`). It shouldn't even let you compile.

This is what you need:

```
if (SkillLevel > 1) {
    System.out.println("Would you like to sign up for medical y/n?");
    Medical = sc.next().charAt(0); // make sure you define Medical as char
    if (Medical == 'y') {
        TotalPay = TotalPay - 23.50;
        System.out.println("\nMedical Insurance cost: -$23.50");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the inner `if` at all.

```
if (Medical == 'y') { // Checks if the char Medical is 'y' or not
    TotalPay = TotalPay -  23.50; 
    // if(Medical == "y") {  // this line is not required.
    System.out.println("\nMedical Insurance cost : -$23.50");   
}
```

Though you should note that the inner `if` is trying to compare a char on the LHS to a String on the RHS. Moreover, `==` is used for object reference comparisons(in case of non-primitive types), and you must use the `equals()` method for the String value equality checks.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for only entering character `y` then- below is enough,

```
if (Medical == 'y') { // Checks if the char Medical is 'y' or not
    TotalPay = TotalPay -  23.50; 
    System.out.println("\nMedical Insurance cost : -$23.50");   
}
```

But if the user entered `Y` instead of `y` the validation will be false, hope you are not lookoing for this as false. Then you can use-

```
if (Medical == 'y' || Medical == 'Y') {//Checks if the char Medical is 'y' or not
    TotalPay = TotalPay -  23.50; 
    System.out.println("\nMedical Insurance cost : -$23.50");   
}
```

But better to use `String#equals()` or `String#equalsIgnoreCase()`

```
if (Medical.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) { // Checks if the char Medical is 'y' or not
    TotalPay = TotalPay -  23.50; 
    System.out.println("\nMedical Insurance cost : -$23.50");   
}
```